# Dúvida sobre criação de pacote de atualização com o Inno Setup

Tags: instalador, inno-setup, setup

Boa tarde.
Desenvolvi uma pequena aplicação em C#, e montei um instalador para essa aplicação usando o `Inno Setup`. Algumas pessoas que trabalham comigo efetuaram a instalação da aplicação.

O problema é que efetuei algumas alterações na aplicação, adicionei novas validações e afins, porém não quero que as pessoas que já instalaram a aplicação necessitem desinstalar e instalar novamente. Gostaria de saber como gerar ou se é possível gerar um pacote de atualização para minha aplicação pelo `Inno Setup` onde os usuários apenas executem esse pacote e ele atualize a aplicação.

O `Inno Setup`  gera um arquivo `.iss` que quando compilado, ele gera o instalado, o código contido no arquivo `.iss` está descrito abaixo.

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "Gerador de Chave de Acesso"
#define MyAppVersion "2.2"
#define MyAppPublisher "My Company, Inc."
#define MyAppURL "http://www.example.com/"
#define MyAppExeName "GeradorChaveDeAcesso.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application. Do not use       
 the same AppId value in installers for other applications.

; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{20337CAE-69B4-4CA1-8C87-A3DC011563C4}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName=C:\{#MyAppName}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
 ; Remove the following line to run in administrative install mode (install         
  for all users.)

PrivilegesRequired=lowest
OutputBaseFilename=Gerador de Chave de Acesso
SetupIconFile=**\***\***\**\*****
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
WizardStyle=modern

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; 
 GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "**\***\***\**\*****"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; NOTE:  
 Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{autoprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{autodesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; 
 Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,    
 {#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall 
  skipifsilent
```

Se alguém já tiver mexido com essa ferramente e puder me explicar, será de muita ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efetuando alguns testes, consegui uma solução mais prática.

Primeiro, o código fonte do projeto deve estar armazenado no mesmo diretório de quando a primeira versão do instalador foi gerada.

Segundo, Você deve alterar o arquivo `.ISS` atualizando e a versão do projeto.

Terceiro, compilar o arquivo `.ISS`.

Quarto, após compilar um novo instalador será gerado, basta disponibilizar esse novo instalador para os usuários, eles iram executar o instalador e ira se atualizar automaticamente caso o usuário já tenha a aplicação instalada.

o Código alterado ficou da seguinte forma (irei colocar apenas as partes que efetuei alterações):

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "Gerador de Chave de Acesso"
#define MyAppVersion "3.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "My Company, Inc."
#define MyAppURL "http://www.example.com/"
#define MyAppExeName "GeradorChaveDeAcesso.exe"
```